# Do not want replace keyword if start with special character (=) in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace the keyword with another keyword, but not want to replace the keyword if it starts with = (equal) sign.

**For example:**

```
$content = "This is my bag and but is =bag".
$replace = 'testing';
$find = "bag".

$ptn = '/\b' . preg_quote($find, '\b/') . '\b/';

preg_replace($ptn, $replacement, $content, $limit =2, $count=2);
```

But this returning: This is my testing and but is =testing

I want: **This is my Testing and but is =bag**

Please help me to write the correct pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Use: `$ptn = '/(?<!=)\b' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '\b/';`

Comment: @anubhava It looks like working.

Comment: The answers is `$processedContent = preg_replace("/(.*\b[^=])({$find})(\b.*)/", '${1}testing${3}', $content);`

Comment: @asiby: Try with `$content = "bag and =bag"`

Comment: @Toto, try it with `$processedContent = preg_replace("/(.*\b[^=])*({$find})(\b.*)/", '${1}testing${3}', $content);`.